# String Replace Operation

Tags: jquery, math, operations

I am modifying a code that I did not write.

The code uses string replace to replace `%d` with the result number (ex: 100)

so `%d` times becomes 100 times

The problem is that I want to do operations on the string replace number.

ex: `%d + 30`, but it seems the code doesn't replace the string for the calculation, and I get `NaN` outputted.

How can achieve the operation?

```
  var num1 = "%d";
  var num2 = "30";
  var compute = num1 + num2;

      function substitute(stringOrFunction, number) {
    var string = $.isFunction(stringOrFunction) ? stringOrFunction(number, distanceMillis) : stringOrFunction;
    var value = ($l.numbers && $l.numbers[number]) || number;
    return string.replace(/%d/g, value);
  }
```

Comment: how are you calling this function. How can you write `var compute = num1 + num2;` without  replacing `%d` with a number. The code is not very clear. Please clarify so that we can help

Comment: There's an argument that says jQuery should not be doing this kind of thing.  Better to have an AJAX call to a service that will do the calculation and leave jQuery to do what it was born to do: collaborate with HTML5 and CSS3 to render the result in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is missing a few steps and I am not positive what language you are using, but I think you need to get the replaced integer and add it to another integer (not a string).

```
var stringOrFunction = "%d";
var num1 = substitute(stringOrFunction, number);    
var num2 = 30; // Integer not sting
var compute = num1 + num2;
```

Again, feels like we are missing a good amount of information that would allow a more accurate response.